# Why Vuejs does not want to update the model from the data received through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

**Expectations:**

The application should work as a socket, only data is received through periodic ajax requests to the server.

**Problem:**

When changing data on the "*client (browser) No. 1*", soon the data changes on the "*client No. 2*". **BUT**, if you now change the data on the "*client number 2*", then the changes on the "*client number 1*" does not occur.

Simply put, the data is not synchronized. The application does not notice changes in incoming data.

**I can not understand the reason.**

**vuetest.php**

```
<div id="app">
    <table border="1">
        <tr v-for="item in items"> 
            <td>
               <div @click="editCell" 
                    @focusout="saveCell" 
                    @keyup.enter="saveCell" 
                    >{{item.value}}</div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**vuetest.js**

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created() {
        this.intervalTrigger();
        this.fetchData();       
    },
    data: {  
        "items":[]
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {            
            if (this.intervalId === 0){
                this.intervalTrigger();
            }

            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            bodyFormData.set('module', 'vueTest');  
            bodyFormData.set('command', 'getData');  

            axios({
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                url: '/vueajax.php',
                data: bodyFormData
            })
            .then(response => { 
                this.items = response.data.items;
            }); 
            return; 
        },
        sendAjax(data){
            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            var answer;
            $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                bodyFormData.set(''+ i +'', obj);
            });           
            answer = axios({
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                url: '/vueajax.php',
                data: bodyFormData
            }); 

            return answer;
        },
        intervalTrigger: function () {
            this.intervalId = window.setInterval( function() {
             app.fetchData()
            }, 5000 );
            return this.intervalId;
        },
        editCell: function(e){
            if($(e.target).is('.bg-edit')) return;
            $(e.target).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
            $(e.target).addClass('bg-edit');
            $(e.target).focus();
        },
        saveCell: function(e){
            var value = $(e.target).text();
            var answer;
            $(e.target).html(value);
            var data = {
                'module': 'vueTest', 
                'command': 'setValue',
                'value': value
            };
            answer = this.sendAjax(data);
            answer.then(response => { 
                $(e.target).text(response.data.result);
            });
            $(e.target).removeAttr('contenteditable', 'true');
            $(e.target).removeClass('bg-edit');
        }
    }
});
```

**vueajax.php**

```php
<?php

if ($_POST['module'] === 'vueTest'){

    if ($_POST['command'] == 'setValue'){
        $new_value = (int) $_POST['value'];
        file_put_contents("vuetest.txt", $new_value);
        echo json_encode(["result" => $new_value]); die;
    } else {
        $value = (int) trim(file_get_contents("vuetest.txt"));
    }

    echo json_encode(
            [
                "items" => [
                    0 => ["value" => $value]
                ]
            ]
        );
    die;
```

Comment: I would assume your issue is not that the data is not updated but rather not rendered, in which case put a key on the element that has data that will change and in the function that handles the new data then change the key this will force a rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, these issues are down to Vue's issues with reactivity and arrays: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

With this in mind, you could try:

`this.$set(this, 'items', response.data.items)` instead of `this.items = response.data.items`

This forces Vue to rebind that instance variable with the new items instead.

It's also worth noting, you need a key on your loop:

`<tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">` - You'll likely have a console error stating the same.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution.
It helped me solve the problem, but found a bottleneck: your solution works if you comment out this code in the method **saveCell**:
`//$(e.target).html(value);`
`//$(e.target).text(response.data.result);`

Comment: @Ivan Sorry, I didn't go down that far although I'm pleased you found it. Worth noting: Don't do that :) Use a computed prop and a dynamic class against your element rather than manipulating the DOM directly. This will break Vues grip on the element.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Now the reasons for my failures with Vuejs have become clearer.